# JQuery event handling

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a html structure like this :

```
 <div id="nav_holder" style="position:absolute;border-radius:400px;width:0px;height:0px;background-color:#460203;z-index:350px;">
<div id="inner_wrap">

</div>
</div>
```

I am dynamically putting some html code in "inner_wrap"

```
var h_h=$("<h1 class='myh1'>"+$(txt).html()+"</h1>");
$("#inner_wrap").append(h_h);
var linkkk=$(document).find("#txt1link").html();
$("#inner_wrap").append(linkkk);
```

where as all the link have css class as "showlink"

I am writing following code in

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#nav_holder").mouseenter(function(){
show=true;
console.log("in_#nav_holder_mouseenter");
});
$("#inner_wrap").mouseenter(function(){
show=true;
console.log("in_#inner_wrap_mouseenter");
});

$(".myh1").mouseenter(function(){
show=true;
console.log("in_myh1_mouseenter");
});

$(".showlink").mouseenter(function(){
show=true;
console.log("in_showlink_mouseenter");
});
});
```

However  i am unable to get the events for .showlink and .myh1
can anybody please guide me.
I am new to Jquery
Only log which got printed was 
in_#nav_holder_mouseenter
in_#inner_wrap_mouseenter

Comment: Is this the order the JavaScript gets executed? Can you post the full file instead of just pieces?

Comment: Your html structure you pasted doesn't actually include any of the links with these styles or many of the other elements your messing with via jquery. Can you boil this down to a fully runnable test case and post it on jsfiddle.net?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since .myh1 and .showlink are added dynamically, use live to bind event handlers

Try this:

```
$(".myh1").live("mouseenter", function(){ 
    show=true; 
    console.log("in_myh1_mouseenter"); 
});  

$(".showlink").live("mouseenter", function(){ 
    show=true; 
    console.log("in_showlink_mouseenter"); 
});
```

If you are using jQuery 1.7 you can use on/off methods to avoid any confusion/issues with multiple binding styles as below:

```
$(".myh1").on("mouseenter", function(){ 
    show=true; 
    console.log("in_myh1_mouseenter"); 
});  

$(".showlink").on("mouseenter", function(){ 
    show=true; 
    console.log("in_showlink_mouseenter"); 
});
```

Comment: ...or `.on` if you're running jQuery 1.7

Comment: thank you it worked for me :D 
I was unaware about .live() .... thank you very much